# How to change “type” keyword in clone plugin in Logstash

Tags: logstash

clone plugin default use "**type**" keyword.
In my logstash configuration I use multiple times "**type**" keyword and now i need to add **clone filter plugin** in my logstash configuration.
How can i use this plugin without using "**type**" keyword ? Its ok to use keyword but not same with "**type**". **My aim is like below**

```
filter {
  clone {
    clones => ["cloned"]
  }
  if [new_type] == "cloned" {
    # this filter
  } else {
    # that filter
  }
}

output {
  if [new_type] == "cloned" {
    elasticsearch {
      ... index2 ...
    }
  } else {
    elasticsearch {
      ... index1 ...
    }
  }
}
```

When i try :

```
mutate { rename => { "type" => "new_type" } }
```

Like below

```
filter {
  mutate { rename => { "type" => "new_type" } }
  clone {
    clones => ["cloned"]
  }
  if [new_type] == "cloned" {
     # There are some operation like 
     mutate {
         replace => { type => "first_type"} 
     }
     if ... {
         mutate {
            replace => { type => "second_type"} 
        }
     }
     ....
  } else {
     # There are some operation like 
     mutate {
         replace => { type => "first_type"} 
     }
     if ... {
         mutate {
            replace => { type => "second_type"} 
        }
     }
     ....
  }
}

output {
  if [new_type] == "cloned" {
      stdout {
          codec => rubydebug
      }
  }
}
```

I got nothing to see. I can only see "type" in output.

How can i solve this ?

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the version 4.1.0 of the plugin, `clone` is not using the `type` keyword anymore, but the `tags` keyword. So as of now, `clone` isn't adding a `type` field to the cloned object, but it is adding a value in the `tags` array of the cloned object.

So for instance if you do:

```
filter {
  clone {
    clones => ["your_tag_here"]
  }
}
```

You will have a clone with:

```
{
  "tags" => [
    [0] "your_tag_here"
  ],
  # No "type" field is added, you can use the value in tags to do apply your filtering
  ...
}
```

---

**Note**: this behavior is now the default, and in your case that's what you want, but is can be disabled by setting the `ecs_compatibility` to `disabled`, like so:

```
filter {
  clone {
    clones => ["your_tag_here"]
    ecs_compatibility => "disabled"
  }
}
```

In this case, you will keep using the old behavior, and `clone` will add a `type` field on the cloned object.

Source: [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-clone.html)